# How to install Debian Jessie as a persistant install on my 16GB usb from Windows 7 OS?

Tags: debian, windows, usb

I would like to install Debian 64 bits on my 16 GB USB as a persistent, so that i can download packages and install python, c, Python, etc. and learn some new skills without giving up on Windows straight away.

I downloaded 3.4GB iso and tried to install it with Universal USB installer. But Universal USB installer is not taking that iso file and was only taking netinst.iso. So, I downloaded 260MB netinst iso but i found out that it will install from the net but when i booted, it didnt work and was not able to connect to my Wi-Fi or ethernet connection. Now I am stuck.

So, my probelms are:
1) I want to install Debian 8 on 16GB USB
2) I want to keep using Windows 7 till i get comfortable with Debian
3) I want a persistant install so that I can save my work and download softwares and packages on my laptop.

Comment: perhaps it would be easier for you to use a virtualization solution (e.g. VirtualBox)? that would allow you to use the DVD image and start playing with Linux. besides, you can always take snapshots of your VM so you can restore in case you mess something up.

Answer (score 0):

The 3.4 GB image is **not** a live image. It's a full-blown installer with lots of desktop environments, packages for printing, ssh, etc. It could be use to install real (aka non-live) Debian on disks (e.g. hard drives, USB flash drives or even SD cards). If Universal USB installer failed to write it to the flash drive, try [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) or Unetbootin (if you have a *nix friend, ask him/her to `dd` it for you). But as you meant to install Debian to another flash drive, please consider using a DVD to store the installer instead. Also if [the installer prompt for firmware/driver](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch06s04.html.en), download and unpack [the archive](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch06s04.html.en) to another media and plug in (better prepare that first).

If you just only want Python and C, you probably don't need real Debian until you're ready, but just [a live one](https://www.debian.org/CD/live/). The programs you write could be stored in your Windows' partition.

Also, please consider dual booting as that would be a lot more comfortable and faster. But remind to back up fist.